# Set of string tuples in python

Tags: python, set, tuples

How could i find the the set of tuples of string?

For example there is a list of `[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c','d')]`

For me  `('a', 'b')` is same to `('b', 'a')` . Is there any function in 
python which can identify and remove one of them?

Comment: You haven't mentioned if order is important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort your tuples:

```
unique = set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in inputlist)
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c','d')]
>>> set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in inputlist)
set([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])
```

You could extend [`collections.MutableSet()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableSet) ([`collections.abc.MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSet) in Python 3) to encapsulate that behaviour:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from collections.abc import MutableSet
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from collections import MutableSet

class SortingSet(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self._values = set()
        for v in values:
            self.add(v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{}({}) at {:x}>'.format(
            type(self).__name__, list(self._values), id(self))

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return tuple(sorted(value)) in self._values

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._values)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)

    def add(self, value):
        self._values.add(tuple(sorted(value)))

    def discard(self, value):
        self._values.discard(tuple(sorted(value)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c','d')]
>>> sset = SortingSet(inputlist)
>>> sset
<SortingSet([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]) at 106b74c50>
>>> ('d', 'c') in sset
True
```

Comment: Please check with `OP` if your output is correct in this case: `>>> set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in [('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')])
set([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
list_ = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c','d')]

set_ = set(frozenset(tuple) for tuple in list_)

print(set_)
```

?  Tested on CPython 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far do not preserve order at all, if that is important to you then use this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> items = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c','d')]
>>> OrderedDict((frozenset(x), x) for x in items).values()
[('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')]
```

This keeps the order and you said you could remove one of the duplicates (which it keeps the last)

Also the answers given so far also alter the elements:

```
>>> set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in [('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')])
set([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])
>>> set(frozenset(tuple) for tuple in [('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')])
set([frozenset(['a', 'b']), frozenset(['c', 'd'])])
```

This will keep the elements the same

```
>>> OrderedDict((frozenset(x), x) for x in [('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')]).values()
[('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')]
```